# Redirecting curl REST API Call to File Doesn't Work with Large Payload

Tags: linux, rest, curl, file-io, io-redirection

This works & writes to the file with no issues:

```
curl -x myproxy.baseurl.com:80 -H "Authorization: Token mytoken" https://app.api.com/?status=Approved > output.txt
```

This sends the output to the command line & hangs until I hit ctl-c:

```
curl -x myproxy.baseurl.com:80 -H "Authorization: Token mytoken" https://app.api.com/?status=Approved&page_size=100000 > output.txt
```

Are there some kind of payload size limitations? The length of the JSON response in the first call is 270,928 characters. The length of the second, two parameter, call is 622,133.

Could it be a time-out issue? The first payload takes ~5 seconds, and the second payload takes ~11 seconds when testing with SoapUI.

UPDATE: If I don't ctl-c on the second call, eventually curl does time out: `curl: (28) connect() timed out!`

UPDATE 2: FWIW, this is part of a shell script I am writing, so yeah, it is a programming problem. :P

Comment: there is no such limit in curl, no. could be a limit from the api, though

Comment: You may be on to something. There may be something funky going on with the second parameter. The call with `page_size` produces a zero size file. I can tell it is a new file from the timestamp alone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure to quote your URL because the shell is interpreting the ampersand to put curl in the background.

```
curl -x myproxy.baseurl.com:80 -H "Authorization: Token mytoken" "https://app.api.com/?status=Approved&page_size=100000" > output.txt
```